# Automate Postgres (or any DB) query results (.csv) to be stored in S3 Bucket

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, automation

I think I have a pretty simple, conceptual question.

I have a database where I run queries. Lets just say its a postgres database to make things simple.

I would like to run a certain query on a schedule ... Lets say every night ... And store the results of that query to a .csv file that is uploaded automatically to a certain S3 bucket.

I know people have been able to implement this workflow with Jenkins, but I am looking for a simpler solution. Any ideas?

Comment: have you looked into writing an AWS Lambda ?

Comment: not familiar but will look into it ... figured this was a fairly stereotypical use case with a fairly easy solution but maybe I am naive